# how to use the `map` family command in **purrr** pacakge to swap the columns across rows in data frame?

Tags: r, dictionary, vectorization, tidyverse, purrr

Imagine there are 4 cards on the desk and there are several rows of them (e.g., 5 rows in the demo). The value of each card is already listed in the demo data frame. However, the exact position of the card is indexed by the *pos* columns, see the demo data I generated below.

To achieve this, I swap the cards with the `[]` function across the rows to switch the cards' values back to their original position. The following code already fulfills such a purpose. To avoid explicit usage of the loop, I wonder whether I can achieve a similar effect if I use the vectorization function with packages from **tidyverse** family, e.g. *pmap* or related function within the package **purrr**?

```
# 1. data generation ------------------------------------------------------
rm(list=ls())
vect<-matrix(round(runif(20),2),nrow=5)
colnames(vect)<-paste0('card',1:4)

order<-rbind(c(2,3,4,1),c(3,4,1,2),c(1,2,3,4),c(4,3,2,1),c(3,4,2,1))
colnames(order)=paste0('pos',1:4)
dat<-data.frame(vect,order,stringsAsFactors = F)

# 2. data swap ------------------------------------------------------------
for (i in 1:dim(dat)[1]){
  orders=dat[i,paste0('pos',1:4)]
  card=dat[i,paste0('card',1:4)]
  vec<-card[order(unlist(orders))]
  names(vec)=paste0('deck',1:4)
  dat[i,paste0('deck',1:4)]<-vec
}
dat
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use `pmap_dfr` :

```
card_cols <- grep('card', names(dat))
pos_cols <- grep('pos', names(dat))

dat[paste0('deck', seq_along(card_cols))] <- purrr::pmap_dfr(dat, ~{
    x <- c(...)
    as.data.frame(t(unname(x[card_cols][order(x[pos_cols])])))
})
dat

#  card1 card2 card3 card4 pos1 pos2 pos3 pos4 deck1 deck2 deck3 deck4
#1  0.05  0.07  0.16  0.86    2    3    4    1  0.86  0.05  0.07  0.16
#2  0.20  0.98  0.79  0.72    3    4    1    2  0.79  0.72  0.20  0.98
#3  0.50  0.79  0.72  0.10    1    2    3    4  0.50  0.79  0.72  0.10
#4  0.03  0.98  0.48  0.06    4    3    2    1  0.06  0.48  0.98  0.03
#5  0.41  0.72  0.91  0.84    3    4    2    1  0.84  0.91  0.41  0.72
```

One thing to note here is to make sure that the output from `pmap` function does not have original names of the columns. If they have the original names, it would reshuffle the columns according to the names and output would not be in correct order. I use `unname` here to remove the names.

Comment: why the transpose (`t`) is needed for the output data?

Comment: Because when you do `as.data.frame`/`data.frame` on a vector it returns one column dataframe. We need a wide dataframe with one element in each column, `t` does that.